# Как извлечь из списка с несколькими уровнями вложенности нужный элемент при условии что на первом уровне значение элемента совпадает с определенным?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как при клике на кнопку обойти весь список,  найти в этом списке тот элемент у которого текст совпадает со значением в кнопке?

Если совпадение найдено, то извлечь у найденного элемента всех потомков li, 1, 2 или 3 уровня?
При клике на кнопку я обхожу список и ищу у кго из родителей есть совпадения со значением в кнопке, если нашел, мне нужно извлечь текст например

> 28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##1350 28-

```js
$('.opr').click(function() {
  var opr = $(this).val();
  $('.calc_haracteristics>ul>li').each(function(i, kvart) {
    if ($(kvart).children('span').text() == opr) {
      console.log('Объект найден');
      //но как добраться сюда 28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##1350....?
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Определенное значние: <input class="opr" type="button" value="Однокомнатная квартира">
<div class="calc_haracteristics">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Однокомнатная квартира</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>IP-розетка интернет</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>IP-розетка</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##80##90##monolit##260 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##80##90##brick##200 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##80##90##gyps##140 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Электрощиток</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Монтаж встраиваемого щита до 24 модулей</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##1350 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##monolit##3000 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##brick##1950 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Монтаж встраиваемого щита до 72 модулей</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##brick##6500 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##4500 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##monolit##10000 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Монтаж встраиваемого щита до 36 модулей</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##monolit##4000 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##brick##2600 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##1800 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Монтаж встраиваемого щита до 12 модулей</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##monolit##2400 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##brick##1560 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##1080 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Монтаж встраиваемого щита до 48 модулей</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##monolit##6000 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##brick##3900 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##450##500##gyps##2700 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Выключатель</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Выключатель</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##155##161##brick##190 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##155##161##gyps##130 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##155##161##monolit##250 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Люстра</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Люстра</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##2300##2800####400 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Розетки внутренние с/з</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Розетка</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##95##105##monolit##260 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span></span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##95##105##brick##200 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##95##105##gyps##140 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Точечный светильник</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Точечный светильник</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40##120##140####190 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>ТВ-розетка</span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>ТВ розетка</span>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40####161##monolit##260 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40####161##brick##200 </li>
                <li>
                  28-44##15##4##15##4##5##25##40####161##gyps##140 </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Двухкомнатная квартира</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span></span>
          <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Трехкомнатная квартира</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span></span>
          <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Четырехкомнатная квартира</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span></span>
          <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

пробовал так

`$(kvart, ul>li>ul>li>ul>li).text()` но это какая то фигня, не то..
с помощью children пробовал добавлять но пусто, может быть есть короткий способ, то есть указать переменную kvart и сказать найди мне элемент `'ul>li>ul>li>ul>li'`?

нужен способ чтобы осталась переменная kvart от которой я уже смогу углубляться. но вот как от нее идти не пойму.. (уровень вложености меняться не будет, то есть искомый элемент , если он есть, всегда будет на определенном уровне)

Comment: не понятен вопрос

Comment: а почему `$(kvart).find($('li > ul > li > ul > li'));` не то? вроде почти нужные данные...

Comment: @Санитариум дополнил втпрос

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов помогло, что надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже что структура может быть любого уровня вложенности. Тогда Вам нужен какой-то признак из какого li выбирать данные. Например, отсутствие тега span (Но луче Вам определить более надёжный способ: через класс или атрибут). Тогда, можно выбрать, например, таким способом:

```js
$('.opr').click(function() {
  var opr = $(this).val();
  $('.calc_haracteristics>ul>li').each(function(i, kvart) {
    if ($(kvart).children('span').text() == opr) {
      console.log('Объект найден');
      var res = [];
      $(kvart).find('li:not(:has( > span))').each(function(j, el) {
        res.push($(el).text());
      });
      console.log(res.length);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант получить все элементы страницы и перебрать их

```
window.onload = () => {
    const R = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    Array.from(R).forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    })
}
```

и уже тут как бы отбор легче будет

Comment: Попахивает костылем...  У меня на странице уже хорошо струкьурированный список надо толкьо извлечь нужное

Comment: я не эксперт в архикетре но это страно что их хорошо структурированого ссписка тяжело найти нужное

Comment: весь список в вопросе, если знаете как, прошу помочь

Comment: я вам предложил самый просто способ если вам смущает что это функция вызывается на document  то ее можно вызвать на любом элементе и сократите выходной массив в разы